# could not get more data if passing multiple params in vue-router from component data, only get first param of data

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

As title, I tried to get data to updatePage from listPage but only get first param of data

**listPage**

```html
<v-icon small
  class="mr-2"
  @click="$router.push({name:'Post.Update',params:{item:item,act:'update', category:categories}})"
>mdi-file-document-box-outline</v-icon>
```

**updatePage**

```html
<span class="headline">
  Post Update ID {{$route.params.item.id }}
  Title {{$route.params.item.title }} <!--  show value -->
  act {{$route.params.act}} <!--  empty -->
  category ID {{$route.params.category.id}}
  category title {{$route.params.category.title}} <!--  empty -->
</span>
```

------ VueRouter
{ path: 'update/:id', name:'Post.Update', component: PostUpdate, },

Comment: Can you post your router page (usually under src/router/index.js)?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to pass objects as route params. If any of those params are defined in your route path, they can only be primitive values (strings or numbers).

Comment: item:item is object as first param